# Некорректный будильник

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

Пишу, будильник, но он срабатывает в заблокированном состоянии когда ему вздумается:

Код по установке будильника:

```
AlarmManager al = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   // date посчитан нормально именно на время которое нужно
    Intent intent = new Intent(this ,MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
    al.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,date.getTimeInMillis(),pi);
```

Код обработки широковещательного сообщения:

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Dialoger.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Код заставляющий показать активность при заблокированном телефоне:

```
private void screen()
{
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    if (km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    }
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
}
```

Comment: Решение проблемы сильно зависит от версии Андроида

Comment: JobScheduler или WorkManager

Answer (score -4):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this ,MyReceiver.class);
```

Запятая поставлена через пробел!!!